# Using argparse for an input file

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse to take an input file like so:

```
python python_script.py --input_file ~/lab_projects/my_input_file.txt
```

and in the script I use `input_file = args.input_file`

When I run my script I get:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: class 'list'
```

because when I `print(input_file)`, I get `['my_input_file.txt']`

How can I get my argument out of the list and as a string? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `input_file = args['input_file']`.

Comment: How are you actually defining the `--input_file` option? Are you using `nargs=1`, by any chance? Don't.

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not subscriptable error with args['input_file'] ?

Comment: I am using nargs='+'

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate on windows and 3.7. I'm guessing this is specific to Unix shells. For example, in 3.6 the `shlex` module was upgraded to better parse [`();<>|&`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#improved-compatibility-with-shells) in Unix shells. Perhaps try including `type=str`? If that doesn't work try combining `sys.argv` into one big string then split again using `shlex.shlex` with `punctuation_chars=True` then pass that to `parse.parse_args`.

Comment: Do you *want* to allow an arbitrary number of files with `--input_file`? If so, the result will always be a list, even if you only specify one argument. You index the list like any other: `args.input_file[0]`.

Comment: Of course! Boy do I feel silly, thanks! Will argparse always default to a list given multiple inputs?

Comment: `argparse` gives you a list with `nargs` like 1,2,'*','+', and with `append` action.  I strongly recommend `print(args)` during the development/learning stage so you see exactly what the parser produces.